# Why do std::forward_list::remove and std::erase<std::forward_list> have different types for value?

Tags: c++, templates, standards, c++20

`std::forward_list` has a [member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/remove):

```
size_type remove(const T& value);
```

and a [non-member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/erase2) `std::erase` declared as follows:

```
template<class T, class Alloc, class U>
typename forward_list<T, Alloc>::size_type
    erase(forward_list<T, Alloc>& c, const U& value);
```

Please note that non-member function `std::erase` has a different type `U` for `value`; while member function `remove` just use type `T` for `value`.

Why doesn't `std::erase` just use type `T` for `value`?

**Is there any design rationale behind the inconsistent?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a practical reason. And it has to do with the difficulties imposed by template argument deduction. Imagine this hypothetical function:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(std::forward_list<T> const&, T const&) {}
```

What do you get for this invocation?

```
std::forward_list<double> l;
foo(l, 1);
```

The answer is that you get an error in template argument deduction. According to one argument `T` is double, but according to the other it's int. If I was to write `erase`, I'd use two different template arguments as well, if only to avoid such issues in innocent code.

Now `remove` is not a member template, it is a regular member function of any specialization. So you can write, without problem:

```
std::forward_list<double> l;
// later
l.remove(1);
```

`1` is an integer, it doesn't match the `double` that `remove` expects. However, that is not a problem. Because `remove` is a regular member function of a concrete specialization, and an implicit conversion is possible.

Comment: The fact that it’s not just `type_identity_t<T>` tells us that the heterogeneous comparison issue from the other answer is relevant—but so is this.

Answer (score 2):

As it is pointed out on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/erase2):

> Unlike std::forward_list::remove, erase accepts heterogenous types and
>   **does not force a conversion to the container's value type before
>   invoking the == operator**.

So, for `std::erase()` it is enough to have `operator==` defined for `T` and `U` without imposing a restriction on `U` being convertible to `T` which gives more freedom comparing to `remove()` member function.

Comment: Why doesn’t `remove` use the same technique?

Comment: @xmllmx: For the same reason heterogeneous searches of `map/set` weren't possible for some time: nobody thought of it.